# Function to count number of line breaks acts differently on $(window).on('resize') and $(document).ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize

I have a function which counts the number of line breaks in a div, depending on the width of the window. While the functions works fine when placed in the `$(window).on('resize')` function, it does not work when put in `$(document).ready()` function. I want it to work right on page load, and also window resize, how do I support both?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/BradMitchell/aswex704/1/)

**Javascript/jQuery:**

```
// functions called in both document.ready() and window.resize

$(document).ready(function(){
  var lineCount = getLineCount();
  postItems(lineCount);
  $('.answer').text("Ready");
});

$(window).on('resize', function(){
    var lineCount = getLineCount();
    postItems(lineCount);
    $('.answer').text("Number of lines: " + lineCount);

});


// calculates the amount of lines required to hold the items
function getLineCount() {
  var lineWidth = $('.line').width();
  var itemWidthSum = 0;
  var lineCount=1;

  $('.item').each(function(index, element) {
      if((lineWidth - itemWidthSum) > ($(element).outerWidth())) {
        itemWidthSum = itemWidthSum + $(element).outerWidth();
      } else {
        lineCount++;
        itemWidthSum = $(element).outerWidth();
      }
  });
  return lineCount;
}


// overlays rows for the amount of linebreaks
function postItems(lineCount){
  var container = $('<div />');;
  for(var i = 1; i <= lineCount; i++) {
    container.append('<div class="line">' + i + '</div>');
  }
  $('.line-wrap').html(container);
}
```

You'll see at the start of the page, it incorrectly shows 17 lines, and then once you resize it will show the correct amount.

Comment: Note is redundant calling those methods twice... can simply trigger resize after event handler declared and will do same thing with exception of text differences

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue lies in the first line of `getLineCount()`. Originally you had

```
var lineWidth = $('.line').width();
```

but no elements with the class "line" exist yet on your page (since they get added in your `postItems()` method. I changed it to

```
var lineWidth = $(".container").width();
```

instead, and now your code should be working. Snippet posted below:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var lineCount = getLineCount();
  postItems(lineCount);
  $('.answer').text("Ready");
});

$(window).on('resize', function(){
    var lineCount = getLineCount();
    postItems(lineCount);
    $('.answer').text("Number of lines: " + lineCount);
 
});


// calculates the amount of lines required to hold the items
function getLineCount() {
  var lineWidth = $('.container').width();
  var itemWidthSum = 0;
  var lineCount=1;
 
  $('.item').each(function(index, element) {
      if((lineWidth - itemWidthSum) > ($(element).outerWidth())) {
        itemWidthSum = itemWidthSum + $(element).outerWidth();
      } else {
        lineCount++;
        itemWidthSum = $(element).outerWidth();
      }
  });
  return lineCount;
}


// overlays rows for the amount of linebreaks
function postItems(lineCount){
  var container = $('<div />');;
  for(var i = 1; i <= lineCount; i++) {
    container.append('<div class="line">' + i + '</div>');
  }
  $('.line-wrap').html(container);
}
```

```css
body {
  text-align:center;
}

.answer {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
  display: inline-block;
}

.item {
  height: 50px;
  padding:0 10px;
  background-color: #aef2bd;
  float: left;
  opacity:0.2;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.line-wrap {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top:0; left: 0;
}

.line {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  opacity:0.5;
  color: white;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.line:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="item-wrap">
    <div class="item">Computer Science</div>
    <div class="item">Language</div>
    <div class="item">Marketing</div>
    <div class="item">Biology</div>
    <div class="item">Computer Science</div>
    <div class="item">Language</div>
    <div class="item">Marketing</div>
    <div class="item">Biology</div>
    <div class="item">Computer Science</div>
    <div class="item">Language</div>
    <div class="item">Marketing</div>
    <div class="item">Biology</div>
    <div class="item">Computer Science</div>
    <div class="item">Language</div>
    <div class="item">Marketing</div>
    <div class="item">Biology</div>
  </div>
  <div class="line-wrap">
    
  </div>
</div>

 <h1 class="answer"></h1>
```

Comment: Awesome thankyou! I'm kind of surprised it even worked on window resize with that bug.

Comment: Glad to be of help.

Comment: I also had a similar answer but since you have provided, basically the same answer, Ill just leave this comment. In the `getLineCount` function if you change `$('.line').width();` to `$('.line-wrap').width();` it also solved the problem.